# Could not resolve 'story.detail?storyId=167&pubId=84' from state 'search'

Tags: angularjs, state, parameters, wakanda

Could not resolve `story.detail?storyId=167&pubId=84` from state `search`

```
var params = 'storyId='+$scope.stories[index].ID+'&pubId='+$scope.pubId;
$state.go('story.detail?'+params);

$stateProvider
    .state('story.list', {
        url: '/search?storyId&pubId',
        templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl',
        resolve: {
            ds : ['$wakanda', function($wakanda){
                    return $wakanda.init();
                }]
        }
    })
    .state('story', {
        url: '/story',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/story.html'
        // controller: 'StoryCtrl'
    })
    .state('story.detail', {
        url: '/story.detail?storyId&pubId',
        templateUrl: 'views/story_detail.html',
        controller: 'StoryDetailCtrl',
        resolve: {
            ds : ['$wakanda', function($wakanda){
                return $wakanda.init();
          }]
        }
    });
```

I've read through other similar questions and replies here.

I don't know why router could not resolve the state name `story.detail?storyId=167&pubId=84` from state `search`.

Answer (score 1):

`$state.go` should be configured like so:

```
$state.go('story.detail', {
    storyId : $scope.stories[index].ID,
    pubId : $scope.pubId  
 });
```

Comment: Travis,

It works! Thanks!

I looked through other posts here for this information and copied them.

I read the documentation and partially understood the :storyId syntax. 

I was previously passing an object for parameters and parsing it, but did not understand the url: '/....' syntax you clearly posted here.

:-)

Comment: Glad to help. For more details on routes, see [AngularJS docs on $routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) which the angular-ui $stateProvider uses.

Specifically, see the `.when` method and the `path` parameter on that method for more details on how to define flexible routes.

Comment: Travis,

I spoke early, now I'm getting this:

Failed to instantiate module newsApp due to:
Error: Duplicate parameter name 'storyId' in pattern '/story/search?storyId=:storyId&pubId=:pubId'

on this line:
url: '/story.detail?storyId=:storyId&pubId=:pubId',

Comment: Actually, looks like I was wrong about the state definition. I think you had that setup correctly according to the [docs here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters). 

I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Travis, 

url: '/story.detail/storyId/:storyId/pubId/:pubId',

This works.

Comment: Yes that should work as well.  I prefer this format as it looks cleaner. I thought you had set up query params on purpose and didn't want to suggest changing it if you couldn't.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the & delimiter and it did not work for me. / did work.

Comment: Well, after our changes here is another instance of my initial problem:

Error: Could not resolve 'series.detail' from state 'customers'

Please help!

    $state.go('series.detail', {
    seriesId : $scope.seriesCol[index].ID,
    custId: $scope.custId
    });

    $stateProvider.state('series.detail', {
    url: '/series.detail/seriesId/:seriesId/custId/:custId',
    templateUrl: 'views/series_detail.html',
    controller: 'SeriesDetailCtrl',
    resolve: {
        ds : ['$wakanda', function($wakanda){
          return $wakanda.init();
        }]
      }
    });

Comment: Can you provide more context?  Can you share a link via Plunkr or JsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Rings/4e6tg235/1/

Here is the context for this error. Please help.